# C# - MySql - Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Tags: c#, mysql

Although i saw a lot of post about this problem, non of that could solved my problem.
I wrote a c# code for accesing a database, i downloaded the right connector, added the reference, checked the copy global checkbox.

The code works fine on my computer, it can access database, update it everything, but on my colleg's computer it writes the well known error message: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. 
Ha also got the right connector, i sent the MySql.Data.dll too, he got his database running, just can't connect. He says there is no possibility to use TCP connection on his computer because of security stuff, it could be the problem. Any idea?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace Update 
{
    /// <exclude/>
    public class Update 

    {


        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (args.Length <= 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hiányzó argumentumok\nSyntax:Szerver Adatbázis Tábla Oszlop [USERID] [PASSWORD]");
            }

            switch (args.Length)
            {
                case 4:
                    update(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], null,null);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    update(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], null);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    update(args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3],args[4],args[5]);
                    break;

            }



            return 0;
        }

        public static void update(String server, String dataBase, String table, String column, String userid, String password)
        {

                String str = @"Server=" + server + ";Database=" + dataBase +";Uid=" + userid + ";Pwd="+ password + ";";
                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection con = null;
                MySqlDataReader reader = null;

                try
                {


                    con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
                    con.ConnectionString = str;
                    con.Open();

                    String cmdText = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS konicaminolta;" +
                                     "USE konicaminolta;" +
                                     "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbTemp (company TEXT);" +
                                     "DELETE FROM dbTemp;" +
                                     "INSERT INTO dbTemp SELECT " + column + " FROM " + dataBase + "." + table + ";";

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);

                    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    dataReader.Close();



                }
                catch (MySqlException err)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    if (con != null)
                    {
                        con.Close(); //close the connection
                    }
                } 
            }

        }
   }
```

Comment: If I remember well, when you create a new Mysql login you can specify the host from where this login is going to connect. Even if you don't say nothing about the network in which your're connecting, beware of firewall stooping your packets from reaching the MySql server.

Comment: Offtop: you better use 'using' statement instead of try/finally block for closing/disposing reader and connection. But try/catch block with handling exception has to be kept, of course.